# NSDate filtering cases

Tags: ios, nsdate

I am using a `transient attribute` to distribute `core data objects` in `table view sections`.
The `transient attribute` is called *sectionIdentifier* and it is defined depending on an attribute called *todoDueDate*.
I need to filter the objects in a way that **all must be included** in one of following groups, **and only in one**:

```
1. sectionIdentier = 0, **OVERDUE** , todoDueDate < today
2. sectionIdentier = 1, **TODAY** , todoDueDate = today
3. sectionIdentier = 2, **TOMORROW** , todoDueDate >today AND todoDueDate= = tomorrow
4. sectionIdentier = 3, **UPCOMING** , todoDueDate > today AND todoDueDate!=tomorrow
```

With my current code, I am able to filter the objects for the cases 1,2 and 4(I have to discard here objects for tomorrow). I have tried several ways to filter the objects for the case 3, but no success.
I kindly ask you to help me filtering for case 3.
Here is my current code:

```
-(NSString *)sectionIdentifier{

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    NSString *tmp = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

    if (!tmp){

        NSDate *date = self.todoDueDate;
        NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];


        NSLog(@"date= %@",date);
        NSLog(@"todayDate = %@",todayDate);


        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSInteger comps = (NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit);
        NSDateComponents *date1Components = [calendar components:comps fromDate:date];
        NSDateComponents *date2Components = [calendar components:comps fromDate:todayDate];

        date = [calendar dateFromComponents:date1Components];
        todayDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:date2Components];


        if([date
            compare:todayDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
            tmp = @"0";//OVERDUE
        }
        if([date
          compare:todayDate] == NSOrderedDescending)  {
          tmp = @"3";//UPCOMING BUT NOT TOMORROW(PENDING THIS PART)
        }
        if ([date
             compare:todayDate] == NSOrderedSame) {
            tmp = @"1";//TODAY
        }


   //TOMORROW COMES HERE



        NSLog(@"Tmp= %@",tmp);

        [self setPrimitiveValue:tmp forKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

    }
    return tmp;

}
```

---

Here is my updated code:

```
-(NSString *)sectionIdentifier{

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    NSString *tmp = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

    if (!tmp){
        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        NSDate *date = self.todoDueDate;
        NSCalendar *calendar;
        NSInteger daysAfterToday = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                               fromDate:today toDate:date options:0].day;
       // NSString *section;
        if (daysAfterToday < 0) {
            tmp  = @"0";
        } else if (daysAfterToday == 0) {
            tmp = @"1";
        } else if (daysAfterToday == 1) {
            tmp = @"2";
        } else {
            tmp = @"3";
        }


        NSLog(@"TODAY = %@", today);
        NSLog(@"DATE = %@", date);
        NSLog(@"DAYS AFTER TODAY = %ld",(long)daysAfterToday);

        NSLog(@"Tmp= %@",tmp);

        [self setPrimitiveValue:tmp forKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

    }
    return tmp;

}
```

And here the logging results:

```
2014-01-17 22:35:53.576 To-Do Pro Light[4124:a0b] TODAY = 2014-01-18 05:35:53 +0000
2014-01-17 22:35:53.619 To-Do Pro Light[4124:a0b] DATE = 2014-01-13 04:08:32 +0000
2014-01-17 22:35:53.656 To-Do Pro Light[4124:a0b] DAYS AFTER TODAY = 0
2014-01-17 22:35:53.664 To-Do Pro Light[4124:a0b] Tmp= 1
2014-01-17 22:35:53.739 To-Do Pro Light[4124:a0b] TODAY = 2014-01-18 05:35:53 +0000
2014-01-17 22:35:53.743 To-Do Pro Light[4124:a0b] DATE = 2014-01-18 04:13:39 +0000
2014-01-17 22:35:53.748 To-Do Pro Light[4124:a0b] DAYS AFTER TODAY = 0
2014-01-17 22:35:53.752 To-Do Pro Light[4124:a0b] Tmp= 1
2014-01-17 22:35:53.757 To-Do Pro Light[4124:a0b] TODAY = 2014-01-18 05:35:53 +0000
2014-01-17 22:35:53.762 To-Do Pro Light[4124:a0b] DATE = 2014-01-19 04:16:14 +0000
2014-01-17 22:35:53.766 To-Do Pro Light[4124:a0b] DAYS AFTER TODAY = 0
2014-01-17 22:35:53.770 To-Do Pro Light[4124:a0b] Tmp= 1
2014-01-17 22:35:53.776 To-Do Pro Light[4124:a0b] TODAY = 2014-01-18 05:35:53 +0000
2014-01-17 22:35:53.779 To-Do Pro Light[4124:a0b] DATE = 2014-01-25 04:11:34 +0000
2014-01-17 22:35:53.825 To-Do Pro Light[4124:a0b] DAYS AFTER TODAY = 0
2014-01-17 22:35:53.831 To-Do Pro Light[4124:a0b] Tmp= 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ask the calendar to compute the number of days from today to the due date, and check that number:

```
        NSInteger daysAfterToday = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
            fromDate:today toDate:date options:0].day;
        NSString *section;
        if (daysAfterToday < 0) {
            section = @"0";
        } else if (daysAfterToday == 0) {
            section = @"1";
        } else if (daysAfterToday == 1) {
            section = @"2";
        } else {
            section = @"3";
        }
```

Comment: I will also try your proposal, it seems much easier to implement and needs only 12 code lines. Very clever.

Comment: I have included objects that should be sorted on the four possible groups, but after launching the app all objects are included in group 1...

Comment: You're going to need to provide more details.  Try logging `today`, `date`, and `daysAfterToday`.

Comment: @robmayoff, I have updated my question and put there the logging results.

Comment: Sorry, it is working, the problem was at the NSCalendar definition, it must be  NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]; Thank you

Comment: There is no difference between TODAY and TOMORROW, both are considered as TODAY. TODAY = 2014-01-18 05:53:50 +0000
DATE = 2014-01-18 04:13:39 +0000 DAYS AFTER TODAY = 0
Tmp= 1
TODAY = 2014-01-18 05:53:50 +0000
DATE = 2014-01-19 04:16:14 +0000
DAYS AFTER TODAY = 0
Tmp= 1

Comment: Try setting your calendar's time zone to `[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]`.  Also, try normalizing the time part of each date to noon.

Comment: Also, you might find the [“Solutions to Common Date and Time Challenges” video from WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/?id=227) very helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience. I have used NSDateComponents and   convert the NSDates without time portion, and is working. I will also take a look at the video. Thank you again..

Answer (score 1):

Refatoring your code a little, you can use the message `dateOnly` to return only a date, no time component (put all this code in an `NSDate` category):

```
-(NSDate *)dateOnly {
  unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
  NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
  NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:flags fromDate:self];
  return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

This will return you today:

```
+(NSDate *)today {
  return [[NSDate now] dateOnly];
}
```

Then, given this:

```
-(NSDate *)addDays:(NSInteger)days {
  NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
  [offsetComponents setDay:days];
  return [[NSDate calendar] dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:self options:0];
}
```

You can have tomorrow:

```
+(NSDate *)tomorrow {
  return [[NSDate today] addDays:1];
}
```

From this, you can use `[NSDate today]` and `[NSDate tomorrow]` to simplify your code.

Also, remember to strip the time components from `todoDueDate`:

```
NSDate *date = [self.todoDueDate dateOnly];
NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate today];
NSDate *tomorrowDate = [NSDate tomorrow];
```

Your logic can be simplified:

1. sectionIdentier = 0, **OVERDUE** , todoDueDate < today
2. sectionIdentier = 1, **TODAY** , todoDueDate = today
3. sectionIdentier = 2, **TOMORROW** , todoDueDate = tomorrow
4. sectionIdentier = 3, **UPCOMING** , todoDueDate > tomorrow

In code:

```
if ([date compare:todayDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
  tmp = @"0";//OVERDUE
}
else if ([date isEqualToDate:todayDate])  {
  tmp = @"1";//TODAY
}
else if ([date isEqualToDate:tomorrowDate])  {
  tmp = @"2";//TOMORROW
}
else if ([date compare:tomorrowDate] == NSOrderedDescending)  {
  tmp = @"3";//UPCOMING
}
```

Comment: thank you, I will try your proposal, but I would need your help to discriminate between tomorrow only and upcoming but not tomorrow.

Comment: I would also consider to accept your answer, but the answer from @robmayoff is better to me..Thank you in any case.